# Using Hmisc cut2 arguments - how does the max argument work?

Tags: r, hmisc

I have uneven lengths in my huge data set. I.e., 700 observations for 2016, 400 observations from 2017. I have a lot of years of data, so manually clipping the datasets is not feasible.

I want to cut them both into quantiles for observations, but only the first 400 for each group.=

There is a tantalizing "minmax" argument in the [Hmisc documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/Hmisc/man/cut2.html). Is it possible to use the minmax an argument so Hmisc to only cut quantiles from observations 1-400?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: That `minmax` argument won't help you. That's just a safety net for those who misspecify the cuts.

Answer (score 0):

Using **dplyr**, you can select the first 400 records for each value of year using `group_by` and `slice`. Then create quantiles, either within each year or overall.

```
set.seed(911) # Simulate some uneven data
df <- data.frame(year=rep(2016:2018, times=c(400,500,600)),
                 val=rnorm(1500,50,5))

library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
```

This creates quantiles within each year

```
df %>% group_by(year) %>%
  slice(1:400) %>%
  mutate(q4 = cut(val, 
                  breaks=quantile(val, 
                                  probs = seq(0,1,1/4)), 
                  include=TRUE, labels=FALSE)) %>%
# You can stop here and save the output, here I continue to check the counts
  count(q4) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=q4, values_from=n)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   year [3]
#   year   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1  2016   100   100   100   100
#2  2017   100   100   100   100
#3  2018   100   100   100   100
```

Or you can ungroup to create overall quantiles (counts will differ per year).

```
df %>% group_by(year) %>%
  slice(1:400) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(q4 = cut(val, 
                  breaks=quantile(val, 
                                  probs = seq(0,1,1/4)), 
                  include=TRUE, labels=FALSE)) %>% 
# Stop here to save, or continue to check the counts
  group_by(year) %>%
  count(q4) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=q4, values_from=n)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   year [3]
#   year   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1  2016   116    88   102    94
#2  2017    86   114    85   115
#3  2018    98    98   113    91
```

Comment: Thanks, Edward! Normally I do all my data handling in MatLab and use R to run unusual models or create GIS layers. I want to be able to work more successfully in R relating to data, your detailed explanation is very very helpful and helps move me forward.

Comment: Oh - one note for anyone else who reads this.  dpylr is often also used with the package tidyr, in this case, Edward's use of "pivot_wider" requires the use of tidyr, which is not mentioned.  However, when one installs tidyr, with "install.packages("tidyr")" there is a confusing moment where it asks a yes no question about unpacking and installing.  Click "no" to install the tidyr package without compiling it yourself.